# How to dynamically attach checkbox to list item fetched from database?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have created a list view and fetched data from database into that list view now I want to attach check box to each item in that list view,what should I do please help me?

I have created a check box

```
chk=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)
```

after that when I set value to it like

```
chk.setText(name)
```

where name is the String variable containing fetched column of name from the database it gives me `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Show your full code releated to this & post your logcat.

Comment: Is checkbox there in the view which you are inflating for listview?

Comment: I have to create that check box dynamically as soon as the item gets added into the list view, the check box also must be there with that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you have fetched values correctly from database,as you are getting null pointer error that means you string name or checkbox is null.

Comment: yup I have fetched values correctly from the database.I am not getting why it shows that exception "chk.setText(name)" on this line only.

Comment: have you declared your checkbox variable correctly and the id exists

Comment: No, I have to create it dynamically.When the data gets fetched into the list that time check box also must get created with each item.I have tried so many things but couldn't get it done.

Comment: then you are doing this wrong for creating checkbox dynamically do it like this CheckBox cb=new CheckBox(this); and then assign this into your listview do it right way,thats why you are getting a nullpointer error,google for assigning dynamic views to listview

Comment: membersList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long id) { }     } can I declare check box under this code.where memberList is listView name.

Comment: Please don't do it like this,you have not initialized your adapter here.There are tons of examples on internet just google it.First define your checkbox in layout and then use that checkbox in a well defined adapter and then assign this adapter to your listview.This is an easy process and there are tons of examples,just search and you will be able to do it and upvote my answer as it will help me

Comment: Yess I got it...Thank you so much for your help.Deeply apreiciated...thanx